# Add two Buttons to the Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, keypad

I am able to add a done button to soft keyboard but I also want to add a Del Button is this possible if yes please tell me how ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create an sample.xml layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="#e4e4e4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:text="Done"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:text="Del"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Create the Sample.java Activity file**

```
public class Sample extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);
    }
}
```

Make sure you add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest file like below.

```
<activity android:name=".Sample"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

[image]

Comment: Not only one Activity will need to customer soft keypad , I hope it will be used in other Activity.